# Unity2D - fill amount edge indicator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas

im working on  racing game and there is a panel that shows how far the player has traveled. i want to place an icon at the egde of the horizontal fill amount image to indicate the current position on the panel..
this calculate the fill amount

```
public void Update() {
    progress = playerTransform.position.x / totaldistance;
    loading.fillAmount = progress;
}
```

how do i place an image on the edge of the horizontal fill amount image?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't anchoring your image to the side that move automatically(Based of progress) handle that for you?

Comment: @Eddge That depends on how the progress bar fills up. Not all progress bars are filled using scale. E.g. using an alpha cutout shader (like [my own](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/alpha-cutout-shaders-16429)) won't change any positional data.

Comment: @Draco18s I didn't mention scale, I mentioned anchoring, as there are numerous ways to do this, 1 being using a plain image, and changing the ImageType to fill and then horizontal fill, then anchoring I can see not working, however if he is using unity's built-in slider(Which isnt filled using scale either), simply anchoring his image on the "fill" object that gets created with it, will move the image automatically with the sliders value.

Comment: @Eddge As I said, it *entirely* depends on how the progress is being rendered. And I suspect, based on the field name `fillAmount` that the fill is being handled by the GPU.

Comment: @Draco18s indeed, which is why I worded my first comment as a question instead of telling OP "Just anchor the image to the side that moves."

Comment: Check out how he does the boss's life bar in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXefXSD2SM0

Answer (score 0):

```
float width = lProgress.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;
Vector3 tempV = indicator.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
tempV.x = -width/2;
tempV.x += width * lProgress.fillAmount;
indicator.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = tempV;
```

I know this is an old question, I found the solution today. Thought it might be helpful to others.